# Amplify The instance member 'Products' can't be accessed in an initializer

Tags: flutter, dart, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I have a schema like this

```
type Store @model @key(name: "storesByDate", fields: ["type", "createdAt"], queryField: "storesByDate") @auth(rules: [{allow: private, operations: [read]}, {allow: groups, groups: ["Administrators"], operations: [read, create, update, delete]}]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  type: String!
  description: String
  createdAt: String!
  Products: [Products] @connection(keyName: "byStore", fields: ["id"])
}
```

I added amplify to my project and it generated models like this with these errors
[image]

I don't think I am supposed to edit these files as they are auto generated. But can't understand why it generating wrong codes?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

It would help to change your 'Products' key name to lowerCase 'products'. The problem is your model property name conflicts with another function or property name. It would be best if you changed your property name.

```
type Store @model @key(name: "storesByDate", fields: ["type", "createdAt"], queryField: "storesByDate") @auth(rules: [{allow: private, operations: [read]}, {allow: groups, groups: ["Administrators"], operations: [read, create, update, delete]}]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  type: String!
  description: String
  createdAt: String!
  products: [Products] @connection(keyName: "byStore", fields: ["id"])
}
```